# NSBundle (not yet loaded)

Tags: ios, swift, nsbundle

I'm trying to create an `UIImage` from an asset (icon). My code is roughly:

```
public class MyModule: NSObject {
}

let classBundle = NSBundle(forClass: MyModule.self)
let bundleURL = classBundle.URLForResource("WeatherUI", withExtension: "bundle")
let bundle = NSBundle(URL: bundleURL!)
print(bundle)

// "foo" corresponds to foo.imageset
let image = UIImage(named: "foo", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
```

`image` is alway nil. Printing out bundle:

```
Optional(NSBundle </Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyModule-dxpuooiqxaovvrbdrptwxiypbvwh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyModule.framework/MyModule.bundle> (not yet loaded))
```

The path is valid (I `ls`ed it). Also note the `not yet loaded`. I tried resetting the simulator. I also tried `bundle?.load()`, but this results in:

```
2016-07-15 15:55:24.051 MyModule_Example[25549:306130] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x7fc204880770 </Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyModule-dxpuooiqxaovvrbdrptwxiypbvwh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyModule.framework/MyModule.bundle> (not loaded)
```

Note the `not loaded`. I also tried deleting `DerivedData`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am encountering the same problem. Did you find the answer ?